# reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock is deprecated

Tags: ios

Hello i have come across a warning using mantle cocoapods 
it's "reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock is deprecated: Replaced by +transformerUsingForwardBlock:reverseBlock"

My code:

```
 + (NSValueTransformer *)conditionDescriptionJSONTransformer {
return [MTLValueTransformer reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock:^(NSArray     *values) {
    return [values firstObject];
} reverseBlock:^(NSString *str) {
    return @[str];
}];
}
```

So what i'm asking is how can i update this code to get rid of the error?

I'm pretty new to mantle so the help is greatly appreciated :]

Comment: Have you tried following what the warning says?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to revert back to a previous version...

The old way:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)dateJSONTransformer{

     return [MTLValueTransformer reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock:^(NSString *str){
                  return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:str.floatValue];
            } reverseBlock:^(NSDate *date) {
                  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [date timeIntervalSince1970]];
            }];
}
```

The new way:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)dateJSONTransformer{

     return [MTLValueTransformer transformerUsingForwardBlock:^(NSString *str, BOOL *success, NSError **error){
                  return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:str.floatValue];
            } reverseBlock:^(NSDate *date, BOOL *success, NSError **error) {
                  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [date timeIntervalSince1970]];
            }];
}
```

In short:

Replace: `reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock` with `transformerUsingForwardBlock`

Change: `^(NSString *str)` to `^(NSString *str, BOOL *success, NSError **error)`

Change: `^(NSDate *date)` to `^(NSDate *date, BOOL *success, NSError **error)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok Nevermind on this problem. My fix was to downgrade my pod from mantle 2.0 to 1.3.1

In step order

1- cd to my project using terminal

2- command pico

3 Write out the pods you need - in my case it was  pod 'Mantle', '1.3.1'

4 save and rewrite

5 Install pod by command- pod install

I had this problem when my pods were updated and the code was depreciated. By doing this my code works again perfectly